# Eigenfunction expansion of a heat equation with Legendre polynomials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, legendre-polynomials

I am trying to solve the following PDE by performing an eigenfunction expansion:
$$
\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = -\cos \varphi \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} + D\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial \varphi^2}. 
$$
I perform the standard procedure of separation of variables and write $p(x,\varphi,t)=X(x)\Phi(\varphi)T(t)$. This should yield (if I have not mistaken)
$$
\frac{dT}{dt} = \lambda_1 T \\
\frac{dX}{dx} = \lambda_2 X \\
\frac{d^2 \Phi}{d\varphi^2}  = \frac{1}{D}(\lambda_1+\lambda_2 \cos \varphi)\Phi 
$$
By performing a variable substitution $u=\cos \varphi$, the third equation becomes
$$
(1-u^2)\frac{d^2\Phi}{du^2} - u\frac{d\Phi}{du}-\frac{1}{D}(\lambda_1+\lambda_2 u)\Phi=0.
$$
This reminds me of the associated Legendre equation
$$
(1-x^2)P''(x)-2xP'(x)-\frac{m^2}{1-x^2}P(x)+l(l+1)P(x)=0
$$
Still they have some difference, for example the lack of prefactor 2 before the first derivative, and also the term $\lambda_2 u\Phi$. Is it possible to somehow get the solution of $\Phi$ in terms of Legendre polynomials?

Feel free to check any possible algebraic mistakes I made. I make them quite often.

Comment: For what it's worth, Mathematica does not provide a solution to your equation for $\Phi$. Also, I find the same equation when working through the algebra. Is there any reason to expect to find a `nice' solution?

Comment: @Sal There is actually no reason to expect that. I simply thought are there any possible transformations on the Legendre equations or other special functions not known to me that can be used to deal with the problem. If not then I guess series expansion would be the only way to go?

Comment: Trying a series solution, I find a three term recurrence relation, which is not as pleasant as the two term recurrences in the Legendre equation. It is progress since you can then construct the solution to any desired order, but solving the recurrence relation for the coefficients explicitly seems as difficult as the original DE. Possibly, there is a transformation which casts your equation in a form with `nicer' recurrence relations, but I do not see it. Alternatively, you could consider approximation methods such as WKB to find approximate solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation for $\Phi$ is actually [Mathieu's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function). The standard form of the equation is
$$
\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} + (a - 2 q \cos(2x)) y = 0.
$$
If we take the substitution $v = 2 x$, the resulting equation will have the same form as the one you have.

Next allow me to summarize some properties of Mathieu's equation that might be useful to you.
While solutions to Mathieu's equation exist for arbitrary values of $a$ and $q$, only at special values of $a$ and $q$ are there periodic solutions.
(Judging by the substitution $u = \cos\varphi$ you attempted, I'm guessing that you are looking for solutions periodic in $\varphi$.)
Usually $q$ is treated as the free parameter, and the corresponding values of $a$ are arranged in two sequences, $a_n(q)$ and $b_n(q)$. (The index usually starts at $0$ for $a_n$, and $1$ for $b_n$.) You can think of $a_n$ and $b_n$ as eigenvalues of the differential operator $\partial_x^2 - 2 q \cos(2x)$ on $[-\pi, \pi]$.

The eigenfunctions corresponding to $a_n$ are even functions that are analogues to cosines, denoted $\operatorname{ce}_n(x, q)$, and  $\operatorname{se}_n(x, q)$, those corresponding to $b_n$, are sine-like odd functions. The periodicity of these functions alternates as $n$ increases. When $n$ is odd, they are $2\pi$-periodic, but when $n$ is even, the period is $\pi$. This is important for your application, because when we made the change of variables to $v = 2x$, we are effectively only considering the $\pi$-periodic Mathieu functions, i.e. $\operatorname{ce}_{2n}$ and $\operatorname{se}_{2n}$.

Finally, to properly answer your question "is it possible to somehow get the solution of $\Phi$ in terms of Legendre polynomials", I don't think it is. While associated Legendre polynomials can be [expressed in terms of hypergeometric functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/14.3), the Wikipedia page linked above argues that Mathieu functions cannot.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful. Does that mean $\Phi(\varphi)=A \operatorname{ce}_{2n}(\varphi/2, q)+B \operatorname{se}_{2n}(\varphi/2,q)$ would be the correct ansatz for our case?

Comment: No, actually. This is the part where the analogy to trig functions breaks down. Even with the same $q$ and $n$, the two functions $\operatorname{ce}_{2n}(x, q)$ and $\operatorname{se}_{2n}(x, q)$ have distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: So does the solution maybe look something like $p(x,\varphi,t)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty e^{\mu_{1,i} t} e^{\lambda_{1,i} x} \operatorname{ce}_{2i}(x,q_{1,i}) + \sum_{i=1}^\infty e^{\mu_{2,i} t} e^{\lambda_{2,i} x} \operatorname{se}_{2i}(x,q_{2,i})$? If so, then where would $a$ fit in?

Comment: Yes, that's the form of the general solution. The $a(q)$'s will be related to $\lambda_2$, because they determine the coefficient of the $\Phi$ term in the standard form and your $\Phi$ equation, respectively. Of the parameters $D, \lambda_1,$ and $\lambda_2$, you have the freedom to set the value of two and determine the third from the other two.

Comment: Thanks, another question: Is there a general solution to equations like $\operatorname{ce}_n(x,q)=0$ and $\operatorname{se}_n(x,q)=0$ in terms of $q$? I looked through the properties and did not find anything that can deal with this. What I'm trying to deal with is the PDE as in the question with boundary conditions: $p(x,\varphi,t)=0$ for $x=0, \cos \varphi < 0$ and $x=L, \cos \varphi >0$.